# InverseBindingAdapter not working, Getting error: <identifier> expected in generated Java code

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

I am trying to create a Custom binding adapter to convert `EditText` text to Long and reverse.

This is my bindingAdapter class

```
class CustomBindingUtils {

    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    fun setLong(editText: EditText, value: Long) {
        editText.setText(value.toString())
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    fun getLong(editText: EditText): Long {
        val textValue = editText.text.toString()
        if (textValue.isDigitsOnly()) {
            return textValue.toLong()
        }
        return 0L
    }

}
```

View that uses the custom binding adapter:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/payeeAmountInput"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@={payee.amount}"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/payeeNameInput"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/removePayeeButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But when I click on build, I am getting the following error from the generated Java class.

```
/home/xxxxx/Works/AppTest/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/xxxxxx/groupsplit/databinding/LayoutPayeeItemBindingImpl.java:31: error: <identifier> expected
            long callbackArg_0 = mBindingComponent.null.getLong(payeeAmountInput);
                                               ^
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `BindingAdapter` into a companion object and annotate `@JvmStatic`:

```
companion object {
    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setLong(editText: EditText, value: Long) {
        editText.setText(value.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this `long callbackArg_0 = mBindingComponent.null.getLong(payeeAmountInput);` error because it tries to get a long value from the `EditText` while it found it `null` as using the `=` sign makes it a two-way databinding

Comment: I want it as a two way databinding.

Comment: Also it does not make sense the value of edit text to be null, because this is happening in build time not at runtime

Comment: Doing the step 2 did the trick, I moved the methods to a companion object and added @JvmStatic. Can you modify the answer to remove the step 1. I will mark it answered once you have done that.

Comment: Wrapping in companion object is the correct answer. Worked for me. Thanks!